# is this workaround/architecture/approach correct using classes (complex properties)?

Tags: vb.net, oop, class, architecture

I'm kind of confused using OOP, I mean, I already know (or I guess) what's a Class, and Object, a Method, a property and things like that, but I have this doubt:

Let's supppose I have a class "Laundry" this class has (just for this example) 3 properties:

1. laundryID
2. Name
3. Washers

Id and Name are "primitive" types or simple types (integer and string), but Washers, represent a list of object of type "Washer", that has 3 properties:

1. washerID
2. laundryID
3. capacity
4. brand

All of them (for this example) simple/primitives types (integer,string,string).

So this my dilemma, it is correct to have a constructor like this (VB .net)

```
public sub new(ByVal laundryID as integer)
       '' Here I'll query for the data of the Laundry on DB
       '' After that I will query for every washer that belongs to this laundry
       '' Then I will create a washer object for every row and add it to the 
       '' property "Washers" of the "Laundry"
end Sub
```

And inside of that constructor query for all the washers that belongs to the laundry with id=laundryID parameter, and create objects of type "Washer" and add them to the list of Laundry?

I'm not sure If I explain myself, any comment I'll be really grateful, in less words, what's the correct approach (or good  practices) to work with class/objects that has properties which are complex (other class/objects).

I usually work with ADO.net probably ADO/LINQ/Entity solve this thins in an transparent way, but if they do it I don't really know it.

Note: I'm familiar with VB.net, C#, PHP, so if you prefer explain/help me using examples with its syntax, it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options in the OOP world, I've included two here:

1. Load during the Laundry constructor
2. Load when the Laundry.Washers are first referenced (lazy load)

The main difference here is that if you're loading 1000 Laundry objects (say to display them in a list) you won't have the 1000 individual queries firing off to load their Washers. If someone selects the Laundry and drill down, the Washers are loaded when you need the data.

```
Public Class Laundry
    Private _laundryId As Integer
    Private _name As String
    Private _washers As List(Of Washer)
    Public Sub New(ByVal LaundryId As Integer)
        _laundryId = LaundryId
        ' option one - load them when the Laundry class loads
        LoadWashers()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Washers As List(Of Washer)
        Get
            If _washers Is Nothing Then
                ' option two - load them the first time the washers properties are referenced
                LoadWashers()
            End If
            Return _washers
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub LoadWashers()
        _washers = New List(Of Washer)
        ' load the washers here
        '...
        '...

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is fine.  You are basically saying that you can only make a Laundry Class if you have an ID number, in which case you should probably throw an exception if laundryID is not a valid id number.

I usually expose something like the Washers list as an IEnumerable(Of Washer), so that the consumers of my class can't control the list themselves.

This would be a simple example:

```
Public Class Laundry
  Private _LaundryID As Integer
  Private _LaundryName As String
  Private _Washers As List(Of Washers)

  Public Sub New(ByVal laundryID As Integer)
    _LaundryID = laundryID
    _Washers = New List(Of Washers)
    '// populate washers
    '// throw exception if something went wrong
  End Sub

  '// Properties

  Public ReadOnly Property Washers As IEnumerable(Of Washer)
    Get
      Return _Washers
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

How you create a new Laundry object is up to you.  It could be just an empty constructor, or a Shared function that returns a new Laundry object for you with a pre-populated ID number from the database (or wherever).